# Marcador personalizado con check. Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps

Usando google maps en una app de Android, he creado un título del marcador (marker) personalizado, el cual, contine un texto que da nombre al marcador y un check. Intento hacer una acción al pulsar el check pero no es posible. Al pulsar el check, no hace nada. se marca el titulo en gris (Pero tampoco se como hace este evento). Copio el método.

```
public class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "CustomInfoWindowAdapter";
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater){
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(final Marker m) {
        //Carga layout personalizado.
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_marker, null);
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvNombreZona)).setText(m.getTitle());
        CheckBox cb = ((CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.cbZona));
        if (m.getTitle().contains(getResources().getString(R.string.zona))){
            cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (cb.isChecked()){
                        cb.setChecked(false);
                     
                    }else{
                        cb.setCheked(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            cb.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker m) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

De momento solo intento hacer que se marque o desmarque al pulsar pero no se consigue,
gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si por el momento no quieres tener un evento externo al checked button. Creo que no deberías sobreescribirlo. Porque si en algún momento necesitas saber el valor actual de tu checkbox, puedes llamar al método `isChecked()`. Ahora si por el contrario necesitas realizar una acción con los estados, deberías sobrescribir el siguiente método.

```
satView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
       if(isChecked){
           
       }else{
           
       }
   }
```

}
);

PD: Recuerda que si estas trabajando con marcadores, no olvides sobrescribir los métodos para los listeners, para abrir y navegar cuando se presiona en el marker.

```
gmap.setInfoWindowAdapter(adapter)
gmap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this)
gmap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
```

Segun la documentación:

> La ventana de información dibujada no es una vista en tiempo real, sino que se renderiza como imagen (con View.draw(Canvas)) en el momento en que se muestra. Esto significa que cualquier cambio posterior que se haga en la vista no se reflejará en la ventana de información del mapa. Para actualizar la ventana de información más tarde (por ejemplo, tras cargar una imagen), llama a showInfoWindow(). Además, la ventana de información no respetará la interactividad típica de una vista normal, como los eventos táctiles o gestuales. Sin embargo, puedes escuchar un evento de clic genérico en toda la ventana de información, como se describe en la siguiente sección.

Fuente -> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta. 
No me ha funcionado con las indicaciones. Al igual que no detecta el evento setOnClickListener, tampoco detecta, en este caso, el onCheckedChanged. El check es visible pero no se puede pulsar.

Comment: Creo que lo que esta pasando tiene que ver con la manera como fue diseñada. Actualizaré la respuesta con más detalle